# Will using Ubers user access token lessen the calls to their API via privilege scopes?

Tags: uber-api

With there being rate limits should I ask for an increase when trying to get all access approval? Since my app asks the driver/ rider to sign in using their uber credentials will this help limit the calls to the API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, but it depends entirely on your purpose.

Calls to an API are usually done to get or update data on the home servers, in this case Uber's servers. As such, any Uber specific information you require will likely need to be accessed through their API.

Now, I've not reviewed Uber's API so if you can use the return from the login request to resolve all your needs then great. However, if you need to get data from their servers it would only reduce calls to the API if they require data returned on the login which can only otherwise be retrieved by making another call to their API.